# Quicksilver wants to do "Open URL" on folders

Tags: mac, quicksilver

I am having a problem with Quicksilver β54:  When I type the name of a folder, it is displayed in the Quicksilver window as an Earth (i.e., as a URL), and the only action available is "Open URL", which does nothing.  "Open" is not available.

This happens with some folders, but not others.  I don't know why some are treated as URLs, and others not.

Anybody know why this is happening, or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  The problem is that by default Quicksilver only goes a couple of levels deep in a folder hierarchy, and apparently treats anything deeper as a URL.

See the "Quicksilver doesn't find my files" topic in the [Quicksilver FAQ](http://groups.google.com/group/blacktree-quicksilver/web/faq?hl=en) for instructions on creating a custom catalog set that will scan deeper.